# Как заверстать косую линию на весь экран между секциями?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно на картинке косая линия, как ее заверстать так чтобы адекватно смотрелось и десктопе и на мобильном

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я однажды стоял примерно перед таким же вопросом. Пожалуйста посмотрите здесь: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/721511/234502) Там я реализую кое-что посложнее. Это делаю вручную на SVG. Будет время, попробую реализовать ваш вариант. Всего вам доброго!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1). Вступление.

**Вы пишете:**

> Собственно на картинке косая линия, как ее заверстать так чтобы адекватно смотрелось и десктопе и на мобильном

**Ответ:**

Вначале важно разобраться, что значит «адекватно». В верстке, когда речь заходит про адаптивный дизайн, зачастую бывает два варианта:

1. У нас уже есть макет с дизайном для мобильной версии/планшета. Следовательно мы и делаем так как в данном макете. Может быть совершенно "неадекватно", но что делать, такой дизайн и нужно верстать.
2. У нас нет макета с дизайном для мобильной версии/планшета. И это остается на усмотрение верстальщика, т.е. на наше усмотрение. Предположим, что это наш вариант.

**2).** Реализация.

У нас не просто косая линия, а есть еще цветной бордюр, который нужно реализовать.

Если необходимо сделать просто косую линию, я могу порекомендовать данную **[статью](https://kilianvalkhof.com/2017/design/sloped-edges-with-consistent-angle-in-css/)**, там описывается как сделать такую линию, многими способами.

Наш вариант, с бордюром, я сделал так(лучше смотреть, нажав на кнопку «На всю страницу»):

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.section-one {
  background-color: #5FC18B;
  position: relative;
  padding: 200px 0 350px;
}

.section-one .section-one__title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-one .section-one__descr {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-two {
  background-color: #44a36f;
  padding: 100px 0 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.section-two .section-two__title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-two .section-two__descr {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   begin Separator
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.separator {
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   end Separator
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="section-one">
  <h2 class="section-one__title">Awesome Section - 1</h2>
  <p class="section-one__descr">Not far stuff she think the jokes. Going as by do known noise he wrote round leave. Warmly put branch people narrow see. Winding its waiting yet parlors married own feeling. Marry fruit do spite jokes an times. Whether at it unknown warrant herself
    winding if. Him same none name sake had post love. An busy feel form hand am up help. Parties it brother amongst an fortune of. Twenty behind wicket why age now itself ten.</p>
  <!-- begin Separator -->
  <div class="separator">
    <svg class="separator__svg" width="100%" height="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" fill="#44A36F" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M 100 100 V 10 L 0 100"/>
       <path d="M 30 73 L 100 18 V 10 Z" fill="#308355" stroke-width="0"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- end Separator -->
</div>
<div class="section-two">
  <h2 class="section-two__title">Awesome Section - 2</h2>
  <p class="section-two__descr">From they fine john he give of rich he. They age and draw mrs like. Improving end distrusts may instantly was household applauded incommode. Why kept very ever home mrs. Considered sympathize ten uncommonly occasional assistance sufficient not. Letter
    of on become he tended active enable to. Vicinity relation sensible sociable surprise screened no up as.</p>
</div>
```

**В примерах используется normalize.css.**

Все готово. Адаптивно, и поддержка IE-9+. Это довольно простой код на SVG, написан вручную.

Стоит отметить, что адаптивный дизайн зачастую разрабатывается для мобильных max-width: 320px (iphone-5). И смотря на наш блок, на данном разрешении, косая линия выглядит слишком косой :)

Поэтому, напишем медиа-запрос, для примера возьмем breakpoint bootstrap-3:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.section-one {
  background-color: #5FC18B;
  position: relative;
  padding: 200px 0 350px;
}

.section-one .section-one__title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-one .section-one__descr {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-two {
  background-color: #44a36f;
  padding: 100px 0 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.section-two .section-two__title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.section-two .section-two__descr {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   begin Separator
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.separator {
  bottom: -4px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}


/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   end Separator
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


/* begin Media Max-Width 767
============================================================================ */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .section-one {
    padding: 130px 0 190px;
  }
  .separator {
    bottom: -110px;
  }
  .separator .separator__svg {
    left: -20%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    width: 140%;
  }
}


/* end Media Max-Width 767
============================================================================ */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="section-one">
  <h2 class="section-one__title">Awesome Section - 1</h2>
  <p class="section-one__descr">Not far stuff she think the jokes. Going as by do known noise he wrote round leave. Warmly put branch people narrow see. Winding its waiting yet parlors married own feeling. Marry fruit do spite jokes an times. Whether at it unknown warrant herself
    winding if. Him same none name sake had post love. An busy feel form hand am up help. Parties it brother amongst an fortune of. Twenty behind wicket why age now itself ten.</p>
  <!-- begin Separator -->
  <div class="separator">
    <svg class="separator__svg" width="100%" height="400" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" fill="#44A36F" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M 100 100 V 10 L 0 100"/>
       <path d="M 30 73 L 100 18 V 10 Z" fill="#308355" stroke-width="0"/>
      </svg>
  </div>
  <!-- end Separator -->
</div>
<div class="section-two">
  <h2 class="section-two__title">Awesome Section - 2</h2>
  <p class="section-two__descr">From they fine john he give of rich he. They age and draw mrs like. Improving end distrusts may instantly was household applauded incommode. Why kept very ever home mrs. Considered sympathize ten uncommonly occasional assistance sufficient not. Letter
    of on become he tended active enable to. Vicinity relation sensible sociable surprise screened no up as.</p>
</div>
```

Здесь я использую один трюк из той статьи, которую рекомендовал выше.
Смотреть на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/QOOwQo?editors=1100)

**3).** Заключение:

В заключении порекомендую изучать SVG. Это проще, чем кажется.
Отличное пошаговое руководство: [https://developer.mozilla.org/...](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial)

Comment: Да вы издеваетесь? Единственный ответ делающий именно то что запрашивалось - и удалять?

Comment: Пусть висит пока кто-нибудь не оформит лучше.

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно, не понимаю почему его заминусовали.

Comment: @IvanI Пожалуйста. Заминусовали несправедливо, как я считаю, люди у которых, в некотором роде, личная вражда против меня. Ответ отличный я считаю, если он решил вашу проблему в полной мере, пожалуйста, примите его - поставьте галку рядом с голосованием( https://i.imgur.com/rgdsz1q.png ). Всего вам доброго!

Comment: @PavelMayorov  хм... странно...может у модераторов узнать кто там хочет удалить ?) Если они могут.... А вот вопрос картинкой - вот это плохо точно)

Comment: Не пойму, зачем ты заминусил мой ответ, и сам потом тоже самое написал, только развернуто?!

Comment: @MaxWall Здравствуйте! Минус я поставил, и написал комментарий, за что поставил. Не считаю наши ответы похожими. **1).** В моем есть реализация, которую можно увидеть и применить у себя. У вас только теория. **2).** У меня написан Inline svg, а вы предлагаете поместить svg в фоновую картинку. В вашем ответе, один из пунктов: _«быстро реализуется»_, раз так, я не вижу ничего сложного вам добавить живую демонстрацию в ответ. По-прежнему, предлагаю улучшить вам свой ответ, тогда постараюсь убрать минус, и поставить плюс. Всего вам доброго!

Answer (score 4):

не будет работать в IE  EDGE....

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:#272727;
}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

#content{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #012727;
    bottom:0;
    clip-path:polygon(0 10%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

#triangle{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height:10%;
    background: red;
    clip-path:polygon(0 10%, 100% 0, 100% 25%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <div id="triangle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) вешать стили на идентификаторы - плохая практика, а если нужно повторить такой треугольник на странице?

2) Так много дивов... ради оформления?! Можно один, с before и after

Я бы таким грязным вещам новичков не учил, это плохой код.

Comment: интересно на что вешаешь стили ты....

Comment: на классы конечно. Не обижайся, это не личное.
Если откажешься от стилизации идентификаторов - будет лучше.
Ведь даже перебить их стили  - или "импотант" писать, или каскад.
С ними есть проблемы.

Comment: может мне все сверстать?  это  пример...  один из вариантов...

Comment: какая разница в примере class или id использовать?

Comment: ) Без обид, но ты учишь нехорошей практике, в фоновом режиме. Ответ хороший, но есть мелочи. Я написал о тюнинге, а не минусил.

Comment: в вопросе нет ни строчки кода, один абстрактный пример картинки...))))  вот и пример... один из возможных

Comment: @MaxWall, какие обиды? )))  все ок...  но и я тебе дам совет... когда твой вопрос минусуют ты не удивляйся...  я подобных ответов с ссылкой встречаю всегда в очереди проверок...  ссылка может стать недействительной... а мой пример останется...  так что приведи пример, а ссылку оставь

Comment: Air Здравствуйте! Выше, верно сказал пользователь @MaxWall. **1).** Писать стили на id это плохая практика. У id выше приоритет, чем у класса, из-за этого можно получить запутанный код. **2).** «не будет работать в IE EDGE». Для меня это означает: что это неприменимо на практике. EDGE точно стоит поддерживать, но что и говорить, в большинстве случаев требуется поддержка IE-11. **3).** Ваш вариант не похож на то, что на картинке, считаю, что задание не выполнено. Поэтому, минус заслуженный ставлю вам.  Если в будущем улучшите свой ответ, постараюсь убрать минус. Всего вам доброго!

Comment: Удивлен количеству плюсов. С каких вот на ru.SO поощряются ответы в стиле "держи код и отвяжись"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это мой ответ таком в стиле "держи код и отвяжись"?

Answer (score -1):

```
#triangle-bottomright {     
  width: 0;     
  height: 0;    
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;               
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

Думаю дальше сами справитесь

Comment: Здравствуйте! Я применил ваш код. Он рисует треугольник. В задании, на картинке изображена косая линия с цветным бордюром. Считаю, что ответ ваш неполный, поэтому минус ставлю вам. Если в будущем дополните свой ответ, постараюсь убрать минус. Всего вам доброго!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov здравствуйте.спасибо за искренность и за то что сказали за минус да я понял задачку и написал код треуголника то можно же с этого треуголника создать этот эффект я просто этот код написал за рулем поэтому и так вышло.

Comment: Благодарю за ваш ответ. Я предложил вам улучшить ответ. Вы можете отредактировать его. Здесь есть и мой ответ. Глядя на ваш вариант и на мой вариант, и сравнивая их с той картинкой, что есть в задании, мне кажется, ваш вариант только отдаленно подходит в качестве решения. Поэтому, считаю, что вам стоит улучшить ответ, и довести дело до конца. Всего вам доброго!

Comment: Этот код подойдет для статичных простых треугольников, не тянущихся за ресайзом страницы.
Он не для этого случая.

Answer (score -3):

**текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**Лучше всего - это положить в фон svg-файл, привязанный к низу верхней секции. То есть фоновая заливка идет светло-зеленым, а внизу картинка - темно-зелный треугольник с полосой.
И ресайзиться будет красиво, вот он http://joxi.ru/V2VnOg8SxloPV2

### PS

Этот вариант лучше всего, ибо он:

1) кроссбраузерный,

2) быстро реализуется,

3) векторные треугольники в фоне поддерживают корректный "резиновый ресайз", в отличие от варианта с рисованием треугольников бордерами

4) вектор хорошо выглядит на ретине

Если минусящие товарищи предложат ОБОСНОВАННЫЙ вариант лучше, тогда почему бы и нет, соглашусь с ним. А так - пока сыпется пустое балабольство, нет ни одного варианта реализации такого стиля проще и надежнее.
что собственно и видно - ничего и не предложено лучше )

Comment: Здравствуйте! **Вы пишите:** «Лучше всего ...». **Мой вопрос:** почему именно ваш вариант является самым оптимальным? Также, в вашем ответе нет кода, нечего запустить и посмотреть. Считаю, что было бы лучше, если бы вы привели воспроизводимый пример. Минус ставлю вам. Если в будущем дополните свой ответ, постараюсь убрать минус. Всего вам доброго!